# How to make similar tables in style

Tags: tables

[image]Could somebody lead me on how to draw similar table styles.
I tried using tcolorbox environment similar to this code but it does not exactly match what I want and I couldn't force it to the bottom of a multicolumn article.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\tcbset{enhanced,
        fonttitle=\bfseries\large\sffamily,
        fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
        colback=yellow!10!white, colframe=red!50!black,
        colbacktitle=Salmon!30!white,
        coltitle=black, center title}
\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx={|>{\bfseries\centering\hsize=0.12\hsize}X| 
                              >{\hsize=0.20\hsize}X| 
                              >{\hsize=0.45\hsize}X| 
                              c|
                              >{\hsize=0.20\hsize}X|},
                  title=My table]  
Number of question 
    &   \hfil\textbf{Question} 
        &   \multicolumn{2}{>{\centering\hsize=0.5\hsize}X|}{%
            \textbf{Choose the correct answer from the four alternatives}}
                &   \hfil\textbf{Marks}          \\  \hline
\multirow{8}{*}{\Large 01} 
    & statement A & A statement 1 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
                        & \fbox{}   &       \\  \cline{2-5}
    & statement B & A statement 2 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
                        & \fbox{}   &       \\  \cline{2-5}
    & statement C & A statement 3 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
                        & \fbox{}   &       \\  \cline{2-5}
    & statement D & A statement 4 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
                        & \fbox{}   &       \\  \hline
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Since you mentioned "similar table styles": simila rot what? Including an image or a description of what you want to achieve would also be helpful. Since you mentioned "multicolumn  article": Do you use the `twocolumn` class option or the `multicol` package? Should the table be as wide as both (all)  columns?

Comment: If you use the `twocolumn` option, adding the `dblfloatfix` package might ehlp placing a wide table in the bottom of a page.

Comment: I use the multicol package. yes I want the table as wide  as both columns.

Comment: do you recommend using the twocolumn option?